# Android: SetRequestProperty userAgent?

Tags: php, android, http, post

```
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "??");
```

In the above code: what should `User-Agent` be in for an Android application that is connecting to a web-server to carry post a `PHP Post` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set it, Android does this for you.

Well, you can customise it to your liking using the method you referenced, but you wouldn't be asking what the appropriate value was if that were your intention.